# graphql debugger error unkown type of Query

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am trying to debug a graphql api using visual studio code and node. I get an error in validate.js file saying unknown type of Query. this is occurring in the function "assertValidSDL"
how can this be solved?
let me know what code i can share to show relevant code that can help

Comment: query types definition and used query ... assuming you're using playground

Comment: can you please share your type-defs file?